# Retrieving OpenWeatherMap XML Data using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I'm struggling to retrieve XML data using the getElementsByTagName method. 
I have a document off weather data and I want to pull certain information from this document and store it in my HTML page. E.g.

```
document.getElementById("cityname").innerHTML = weathercurrent.getElementsByTagName("city")[0].childNode[0].nodeValue;
```

However, I either get an error or no data retrieved.

I want to get the city name, temperature, humidity, pressure and weather icon.

XML CODE BELOW:

```
<!--enter code here-->
<current>
  <city id="2643743" name="London">
    <coord lon="-0.13" lat="51.51"/>
    <country>GB</country>
    <sun rise="2017-11-26T07:37:41" set="2017-11-26T15:58:04"/>
  </city>
  <temperature value="6.2" min="5" max="7" unit="metric"/>
  <humidity value="70" unit="%"/>
  <pressure value="1025" unit="hPa"/>
  <wind>
    <speed value="5.7" name="Moderate breeze"/>
    <gusts/>
    <direction value="270" code="W" name="West"/>
  </wind>
  <clouds value="0" name="clear sky"/>
  <visibility value="10000"/>
  <precipitation mode="no"/>
  <weather number="800" value="clear sky" icon="01d"/>
  <lastupdate value="2017-11-26T15:20:00"/>
</current>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to transforms the XML content into an XML DOM, then you can parse the xml.
For example:

```
// Ajax function, gets the content of an xml file and stores it in XML DOM
function getXML_file(xml_file) {
  var xhttp = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');  // XMLHttpRequest object

  // sets and sends the request for calling "xml_file"
  xhttp.open("GET", xml_file ,false);
  xhttp.send(null);

  // sets and returns the content as XML DOM
  xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
  return xmlDoc;
}

// XML file address
var file_xml ='xml_file.xml';

// calls the "getXML_file()" function "file_xml"
var xml_dom = getXML_file(file_xml);
var ar_city = xml_dom.getElementsByTagName('city'); //gets an Array with all "city" tags
```

- You can find more details and example in the tutorial from: http://coursesweb.net/ajax/ajax-xml

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that i have my DOM set up. I am able to retrieve the XML information as a whole, I just don't know how to retrieve specific data using the child, parent nodes and [0] values? So you're saying I can get an array with all "city" tags, but what if I want just the city name, latitude and longitude to store in 3 different variables, what would my code be then? Thanks for you're answer though, very helpful.

Comment: Use `getAttribute()` method. Ex.: `ar_city[0].getAttribute['name']`. Study the tutorial from the link in the response.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me.